# JNLP application starts and before loading stops while launching via marathon JavaProfile Webstart

Tags: marathontesting

Hi my JNLP application strats and then stops after some time. Here is the error

```
`Dec 03, 2019 10:54:46 AM net.sourceforge.marathon.javadriver.JavaDriverCommandExecutor start

INFO: Executing: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaws.exe, 
C:\QThinClient.jnlp][ {JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-DkeepLog=false -Dmarathon.launch.mode=webstart -Dmarathon.mode=playing -Dmarathon.agent=file:/C:/Users/stalin_felix/.m2/repository/com/jaliansystems/marathon-java-agent/5.2.6.0/marathon-java-agent-5.2.6.0.jar -javaagent:"C:\Users\stalin_felix\.m2\repository\com\jaliansystems\marathon-java-agent\5.2.6.0\marathon-java-agent-5.2.6.0.jar"=61197}]

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.awt.AWTError: Error trying to install Assistive Technology: 
com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.com.sun.java.accessibility")
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadAssistiveTechnologies(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.marathon.javaagent.JavaElementPropertyAccessor$InternalFrameMonitor.init(JavaElementPropertyAccessor.java:892)
    at net.sourceforge.marathon.javaagent.JavaAgentHook.premain(JavaAgentHook.java:42)
    ... 6 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -DkeepLog=false -Dmarathon.launch.mode=webstart -Dmarathon.mode=playing -Dmarathon.agent=file:/C:/Users/stalin_felix/.m2/repository/com/jaliansystems/marathon-java-agent/5.2.6.0/marathon-java-agent-5.2.6.0.jar -javaagent:"C:\Users\stalin_felix\.m2\repository\com\jaliansystems\marathon-java-agent\5.2.6.0\marathon-java-agent-5.2.6.0.jar"=61197
Exception in thread "main" Dec 03, 2019 10:57:17 AM net.sourceforge.marathon.javadriver.JavaDriverCommandExecutor start
WARNING: Unable to estabilsh connection with the application(timeout): [C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaws.exe, C:\QThinClient.jnlp][ {JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-DkeepLog=false -Dmarathon.launch.mode=webstart -Dmarathon.mode=playing -Dmarathon.agent=file:/C:/Users/stalin_felix/.m2/repository/com/jaliansystems/marathon-java-agent/5.2.6.0/marathon-java-agent-5.2.6.0.jar -javaagent:"C:\Users\stalin_felix\.m2\repository\com\jaliansystems\marathon-java-agent\5.2.6.0\marathon-java-agent-5.2.6.0.jar"=61197}]
null---------null`
```

If anyone help solve this issue, please.

Comment: Can you provide more details?